# What's a good way to pass the params to service method? An entire object or just some of its params?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

guys, I am new to Java EE, and I'm now designing the service layer. I am very confused about what param should I pass to the method from my controller layer, the entire object? or just its essential params?

For example, if I want to create an article, here is the code.

The first way

```
public void createArticle(Article article) {
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

The second way

```
public void createArticle(String title, String subtitle) {
    Article article = new Article();
    article.setTitle(title);
    article.setSubtitle1(subtitle);
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

so please help me, which way should I follow? I am so confused, thanks!

Comment: In your create method, you are passing the object , then why not just pass the complete object , this will look nice and cleaner. if you want to add some of the additional fields then also using the setters on the object, you can do , before calling the create method.

Comment: Don't expect a clear cut rule for this.

Comment: @AmitK thanks, so it's good to construct the complete object in my controller layer, right?

Comment: @Kayaman lol, It seems like that I am so expecting a so-called best practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service layer implements/dedicated for the business logic purpose.

Both are valid and no harm at all.  They work. And also consider the case where there are 15 paramets to your service method. Coming to the pattern, I suggest you to changethe  way of data transferring. In general what ever we received from client/other to will be DTO's and service layer converts them to DAO understandable entities and the service again converts them back to DTO to proceed it further hiding your actual entities.

```
public void createArticle(ArticleDTO dto) {
    Article article = new Article();
    // some business logic.
    article.setTitle(dto.getTitle());
    article.setSubtitle1(dto.getSubTitle());
   // more business may be.
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

Comment: I have also noticed that in SpringMVC's @Controller class, the method could contain a param called "Model", does it likes the DTO? Oh sorry, maybe I should google it first. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @MarcusLin If you are using Spring MVC, DTO will be given by Controller to you.

Comment: I found it so boring that I need to call the setter again and again, is there any automate mapper tool? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use both, a good practice is not exceed 4 or 5 parameters.

A better practice is to use a DTO (data transfer object, like your Article class) because is easy to read  and provides better support for extend your functionality for new data . The future's you (or your team) will appreciate to avoid refactoring  your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is finally : is your controller should create the structured object and pass it to the service or else should it pass the data to the service as it received them, here individually ?

As a general way, passing a structured object as soon as it is possible produces always a cleaner code than passing multiple parameters in the method and waiting for the next layer to aggregate the object.

Imagine a method like that :

```
public void createArticle(String title, String subtitle, String category, String authorFirstName, String authorLastName, etc...) {
  ....
}
```

It is clearly clumsy and error prone.

For which reason you would like that the controller gives each information individually to the service?
I see at least one case : when we need to apply rule checking before creating the `Article` object and we want to do it in a service layer.
But still, we are not forced to do it in this order. We can check the `Article` rules with an `Article` instance.

Personally, I don't see any good reason to delay the `Article` instance creation.

This seems fine :

```
public void createArticle(Article article) {
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

Choose a way and overall, keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. If you think that in future the `Article` class will expand and could have more field like `publishDate`,`author`, etc then i think its better to go with first approach.

```
public void createArticle(Article article) {
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

Also, going with second way will increase the number of lines in your code. Code should be short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a good strategy to pass an object, especially when you need to pass a number of variables to a method. Instead of passing all those variables just pass the instance of the object to tidy up your method signatures.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like both methods work correctly.
Think on what you want to do with the method later on:

When you already have an article instance it would not make sense to retrieve the parameters (later on there might be also an author and many more parameters so you would have to rework the method of approach 2 whereas approach 1 still works).

However if you want to create the articles on method call approach 2 might be nice to have.

So you see: In most cases approach 1 is better since it is more flexible.
Try to work with the *KISS*-principle: Keep it simple, stupid! (some might know KISS also as 'Keep it short, simple')

Answer (score 0):

---

The question is quite nice. Actually you cant say directly that which method is good or bad it depends on the requirement you have to fulfil in your code . Lets discuss each method

---

**First method**

```
public void createArticle(Article article) {
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

> Generally we pass object to the method as an argument when we need the
>   object to be pushed as it to the other service or when we nearly need
>   all the parameters of that object or the parameter count we need from
>   that object is too high.

**Second Method**

```
public void createArticle(String title, String subtitle) {
    Article article = new Article();
    article.setTitle(title);
    article.setSubtitle1(subtitle);
    articleDAO.create(article);
}
```

> In the second method you have passed parameters generally this method
>   is used when u need just some parameters of the object and not the
>   complete object or the number of parameter is in a small count so that
>   its not tedious for developer to pass all the parameters everytime.